# order by DATEDIFF gives Conversion failed error

Tags: sql-server, date, select, sql-order-by, datediff

I'm editing a query i build in ms sql.
I need to order the items on date, but that gives an error.
`locations_aanvang` gives `2012-08-12`(yyyy-mm-dd). so i extend it to `2012-08-12 00:00:00 +1:00` for EST time.
So to order the i need to convert it to unix timestamp (right?).

The query is:

```
SELECT TOP 6 * FROM jd_lighthouses
WHERE locations_aanvang != ''
ORDER BY (SELECT DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01', locations_aanvang+' 00:00:00 +1:00')) DESC
```

And the error i get is:
`[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

What am i doing wrong? and can i do this easier?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,
Bram Hammer

Comment: why can't you just use `order by locations_aanvang DESC`

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to get... The top 6 what? Newest?

Comment: Is the locations_aanvang field a date type or a varchar field?

Comment: Can you tell as what you want to achieve?

Comment: the locations_aanvang is a varchar.. so if i would order it by that i would get a weird order.
And i want to get the newest ones first.
So i want to show the newest locations ordered by date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because we can'r clarify to question, only help is that:
if `locations_aanvang` is character type then you can avoid error changing code like this:

```
DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01', locations_aanvang + ' 00:00:00')
```

Since you use `SQL Server Native Client 10.0` i assume you have `SQL Server 2008` and `DATE` datatype. To get newest locations use:

```
ORDER BY CAST(locations_aanvang as DATE) DESC
```

Comment: when i do this i still get the error
`Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string`

Comment: This mean `locations_aanvang` not contain correct date. Which data are you store in `locations_aanvang`?

Comment: aa is see the problem.. some fields are filled with `22-03-2012` instead of `2012-03-22`. What to do now?

Comment: It is because there are thinks named domain integrity. That means date must serves as date. This is tip of the iceberg. What about **strings** like `2012-03-07` is it `7 march` or `3 july`?

Comment: So if i understand your answer there is no way to order them? the string is build as dd-mm-yyyy, so 07-03-2012 means 7 March 2012.

Comment: "some fields are filled with 22-03-2012 instead of 2012-03-22" Howcen they be in format `dd-mm-yyyy`? If all dates in `locations_aanvang` column are in format `dd-mm-yyyy`, then you can use this: `ORDER BY CONVERT(date, locations_aanvang , 105) DESC`

Comment: ok thank you i will take a good look at the code and make sure the dates are saved correct.
Again thank you alot for your help!
EDIT: emm if i think your last comment is the answer how should i make it that? because i can't like?

Comment: I don't understand what is your question?

Comment: I wanted to make your comment the answer but i have to do that with the main comment not an additional.
But allready solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.   Let me take a stab.

1. I think MS SQL warns against sorting by a column/calculation that
   isn't directly in return results of your SQL.  This is definitely so
   in Oracle.
2. I'm assumming you can plug in a literal value for your
       variable and it runs just fine?